# I am transferring image file from server side to client, while reading image file i got this issue

Tags: java, android, image, android-emulator, network-programming

I am using following code for reading image file from socket. It reads all the bytes from server because size of file on server and android machine are same. When i open this file it does not open the file and generate error that is the file is corrupted or too large.

```
                public Bitmap fileReceived(InputStream is)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        Bitmap bitmap = null;  
        String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        String fileName = "a.png";
        String imageInSD = baseDir + File.separator + fileName;
            System.out.println(imageInSD);
        if (is!= null) {
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
            try {

                fos = new FileOutputStream(imageInSD);
                bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                byte[] aByte = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead;

                while ( true  ) {  
                    bytesRead = is.read(aByte);

                    bos.write(aByte, 0, bytesRead);
                if ( is.available()==0)
                    break;
                }  

                bos.flush();
                bos.close();
          //      is.reset();

        // here it give error i.e --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
               bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageInSD);



            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Do exception handling
                Log.i("IMSERVICE", "exception ");
            }
        }

        return bitmap;
    }
```

Comment: tries a byte by byte compare, if both files are really identical? [On linux I would try a `diff` at the console]

Comment: what is proper way to transfer image? I tried alot by different ways but I have problem. I compare the bytes they all are same but indexing has problem.

Comment: i changed the code and i have only one problem that is when do I change the most first byte of file in hex editor it correct the file.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use [`available()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29) for this, it won't work reliably!

The docs state:

> [ available() ] Returns an **estimate** of the number of bytes that can be read [...] It is never correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer intended to hold all data in this stream.

Do it like:

```
while ( (bytesRead = is.read(aByte)) > 0 ) {
    bos.write(aByte, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

Comment: its not reading all the bytes the size of file it writes is smaller than original file.

Comment: and it also not terminating the loop

Comment: Oh, of course the *server* must [`close()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#close%28%29) the connection when it has finished sending all data so that the client can realize when no more data is expected. Once the server does that, the client's `read()` will return and eventually return `0` to indicate that no more data will arrive. Note that you may have to set the [`SO_LINGER`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoLinger%28boolean,%20int%29) socket option on the server side to give the client enough time to read all data.

Comment: I have the same problem again. It reads all the bits but when I export file from emulator to PC it generate error while opening the file. Thank for showing your intreast in this problem

Comment: I have opened the file in Hexeditor. If i add one extra bit at the start i.e HEX 89. The image open properly without any error. Kindly suggest any idea if you have.  Thank you